# Two properties of continuity of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I'm studying from Ambrosio-Tilli "Topics on analysis metric spaces" and i think there is an errata corrige. Can someone help me to find the errata corrige book online if there is? However, maybe it is correct and i'm not understanding.

> Let $\mu$ be an outer measure and let $\{A_i\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets. Then the following statements hold.

1. If $A_i$s are pairwise disjoint, then
   $$\mu\left(\bigcup_i A_i \right) = \sum_i \mu(A_i) $$
2. If $A_1 \subseteq \dots A_i \subseteq A_{i+1} \dots$, then
   $$ \lim_{i \to \infty} \mu (A_i) = \mu \left( \bigcup_i A_i \right)$$
3. If $A_1 \supseteq \dots A_i \supseteq A_{i+1} \dots$, then
   $$ \lim_{i \to \infty} \mu (A_i) = \mu \left( \bigcap_i A_i \right)$$

I understand the proof of the first two statements. For the third we define the sets $B:= \bigcap_j A_j$ and $B_j := A_j \setminus A_{j+1}$ and observe that $B$ and $B_j$s are pairwise disjoint.

Now, in the book is written **"{using the second statement}"** we obtain:

$$ \mu(A_1) = \mu(B) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1} B_j \right) = \mu(B) + \lim_{n \to \infty} (\mu(A_1)-\mu(A_n)) $$

But this equivalences is not for the second statement but just for the first one. Am i right?

Furthemore, the second statement is still true if $\mu$ is regular and the $A_i$s are not necessarily measurable. For prove this last statement we know that exist $\hat A_i$ containing them and such that $\mu(\hat A_i)=\mu(A_i)$ and we can do the same with their union $A_\infty$. But, given that it's not necessarily true that $\hat A_i \subseteq \hat A_{i+1}$ for all i, I have to define a sequence of set with this property. Define
$$\tilde A_i:= \hat A_\infty \cap \bigcap_{j \geq i} \hat A_j \subseteq \hat A_i$$.

Is correct to say that:
$$ \tilde A_i = \hat A_\infty \cap \bigcap_{j \geq i} \hat A_j \supseteq A_\infty \cap \bigcap_{j \geq i} A_j = A_i ?$$

In this way i prove that $\mu( \tilde A_i) = \mu (A_i)$. So i can conclude that $\tilde A_\infty$ is a measurable set that contain $A_\infty$ and proved the last statemend using the second statement to $\tilde A_i$

Comment: $\bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1} B_j$ is increasing and it is 2) that is being used, not 1).

Comment: @geetha290krm Ok. So $A_1=\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1} B_j \cup B$. For the first property we have that $\mu (A_1) = \mu(B) + \mu( \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1} B_j)$ and for the second property i can put out the limit. Right?

Comment: @geetha290krm Or maybe easier the first equivalence is due Caratheodory measurability.